# Actualizar con phalcon y vue.js

Tags: vue.js, phalcon

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede explicar como envio un formulario pr medio de x-www-urlencoded en vue.js?

Comment: ¿Qué utilizas para enviar AJAX: axios, vue-resource o alguna otra?

Comment: **vue-resource**
this.$http.put(url, {
        responseType: 'json'
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.message)
      }, fail => {

Comment: Hola YohaBR, **Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad, te sugiero revises [ask] y modifiques tu respuesta, saludos.**